# Backtracking won't go through all possibilities

Tags: python, backtracking

I was trying to solve a problem:

I've got a dictionary that has a question name and some points;

For example `Qs = {"question1": 13, "question2": 1}` , that means the `question1` has `13` points, the second one has `1` etc.

I was trying to create all subsets of questions between `u` and `v` questions and `x` and `y` points.

Here is my code:

```
class GrowingList(list):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if index >= len(self):
            self.extend([None]*(index + 1 - len(self)))
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)


questions = {"Q1":5, "Q2":1, "Q3": 1, "Q4": 4}
u = 1 #
v = 3 # between u and v questions


x = 1   #
y = 7 #between x and y points


solution = GrowingList()

def main():

    Backtracking(0)



def Backtracking(k):
        for c in questions.keys():
                solution[k] = c
               # print ("candidate: ", solution)
                if not reject(k):
                #    print ("not rejected: ", solution)
                    if accept(k):
                                print (solution)
                                if (k == v-1):
                                    return ; 
                                else:
                                    Backtracking(k+1)
def reject(k):
    if len(solution) != len(set(solution)):  #check whether the question already exists
        return True

    points = 0
    for q in solution:
        if q in questions:
            points = points + questions[q]

    if points >y or k+1 > v: #check if the candidate solution has between the given number of questions and points
          return True
    return False

def accept(k):
    if len(solution) != len(set(solution)):  #check whether the question already exists
        return False

    points = 0
    for q in solution:
        if q in questions:
            points = points + questions[q]
    if x <= points <= y and u <= k+1 <= v:   #if the candidate solution has between the given number of points and questions, we found a solution
          return True
    return False

main()
```

So for `u` = 1, `v` = 3, `x` = 1 and `y` = 7 I'm getting only

```
['Q1']
['Q1', 'Q2']
['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3']
['Q2', 'Q4', 'Q3']
['Q2', 'Q1', 'Q3']
['Q2', 'Q1', 'Q3']
['Q2', 'Q4', 'Q3']
```

But I miss a lot of solutions, for example the rest of subsets of questions of 1 element.

```
['Q2']
['Q3']
['Q4']
```

should also be in the solution, and many more.

Comment: What answer would be OK? Do you only accept backtracking? Because the problem itself is fairly easy.

Comment: Not really, but I tried doing backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want, but doesn't use backtracking, in case that was vital. Depending on your needs you might just want to just use the iterator `subsets(qs_between, min_set_size, max_set_size)` rather than turning it into a list.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

qs = {"Q1":5, "Q2":1, "Q3": 1, "Q4": 4}

min_set_size = 2
max_set_size = 3

min_score = 1
max_score = 4

qs_between = [question for question, score in qs.items() if min_score <= score <= max_score]

def subsets(iterable, min_set_size, max_set_size):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(iterable, size)
        for size in range(min_set_size, max_set_size + 1))

result = list(subsets(qs_between, min_set_size, max_set_size))

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really helped me. But for some reason in your example it won't give me only `Q4` as an answer which I believe it should

Comment: I don't think so. I used the example in your code block, which says `u = 1;
v = 3 # between u and v questions`. So 4 wouldn't be there.

Comment: Unless you meant the number of questions in the set should be between 1 and 3?

Comment: Yea, between 1 and 3 questions. But `Q4` is only one question so it should give it as a solution. 
Hope I made myself clear

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward approach

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

u, v = 1, 3

x, y = 1, 7

Q = ['Q' + str(g) for g in range(u, v + 1)]
points = range(x, y + 1)

n = v - u + 1

result = []

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for c in itertools.combinations(Q, i):
        result += [dict(zip(c, x)) for x in itertools.product(points, repeat=i)]

# print result
pprint(result)
```

Some output

```
{'Q1': 7, 'Q3': 7, 'Q2': 5}
{'Q2': 1}
{'Q1': 7, 'Q3': 1, 'Q2': 6}
{'Q1': 3, 'Q3': 3}
{'Q1': 7}    
{'Q1': 3, 'Q3': 4}
```

Looping over the powerset will work as well. For an element `c` in the powerset  you need `len(c)` for the `repeat` parameter.